# How do I update packages in MikTeX 2.9.5671 when I don't have MikTeX console and I get a "connect failed in tcp_connect()" message?

Tags: miktex2.9, miktex-update

I haven't used MikTeX on my laptop in quite a while because I've been using it on my work computer, but with COVID-19, I'm working at home, and I tried to update a document. When I did, I got a message (in WinEdt) about not being able to update a package. I've tried running package manager and update, both as admin and not as admin, and I keep getting a "connect failed in tcp_connect()" message.

I've searched lots of related questions and answers. I don't think my computer is using a proxy server, and I've added the relevant .exe files to the allowed apps in the Windows firewall thing. I don't know anything else to do to check and make sure a firewall isn't blocking it. (While I'm considerably more tech-savvy than the general public, I'm not as tech-savvy as most people using StackExchange!) I don't have MiKTeX console.

I read one suggestion to uninstall and reinstall MiKTeX, but another post said that that can lead to a lot of issues, so I'm a bit afraid to try it.

Please advise. :)

Comment: if you really don't have the miktex console then you didn't update your miktex for at least two years. I doubt that anyone will be able to tell you how such a miktex behaves now and what to do to get it working again.

Comment: You can uninstall and reinstall MikTeX, but you will have to completely remove the old folder (or create a new one) and will lose all your old packages.

Comment: I probably haven't updated MiKTeX on my computer for at least 2 years. I'll try uninstalling and reinstalling. Thank you for the instruction to completely remove the old folder.